# PHP MYSQL - Compare 2 comma separated lists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my Database i have a field with a comma separated list of ids (**itemids**).

For an example i fill some rows with test data:

```
Row   |    itemids
1    =>    2,5,8,11,22,45
2    =>    4,6,9,13
3    =>    1,3,5,16,23
4    =>    6,12,18,21,24
```

Now i have a search string which contains all ids i want to serch for:

```
searchstring => 4,23,40
```

What i want to do now is to get all rows from the database which contains one or more values from my search string. From my example i should get the following rows:

```
Row   |    itemids
2    =>    4,6,9,13
3    =>    1,3,5,16,23
```

How do i do this? Can you give me an example SQL Query?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your table should be normalized. 1 row per id. Could explode the `searchstring` on `,`s and then do a like on each number but then `4` would match `14` and `24`.

Comment: isn't it possible with my approch to have multiple id's per column? @chris85

Comment: Sure it is possible, it is going to be a pain though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: and how can i realize it with my approach? @chris85

Comment: Say your first id were `3` instead of `4`. Your query would be `select stuff from table where id like '%3%' or id like '%24%' or id like '%40%'`. This will bring back rows `2`, `3`, and `4`. Row 3 is returned because `23` matches that like (`'%3%' `). Where as if these ids all had their own records you could do something like `select stuff from table where id in (4,23,40)`.

Comment: Or use full text search by `select stuff from table where concat(',',id,',') like '%,3,%' or concat(',',id,',') like '%,24,%' or concat(',',id,',') like '%,40,%'`

Comment: We are over-engineering it. Its simple and it has been answered. `find_in_set` function is handy in such requirements... And please upvote if you like the simplicity of the answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Query for searchstring => 4,23,40

```
select * from
item_table
where find_in_set(4,itemids)>0

UNION  

select * from
item_table
where find_in_set(23,itemids)>0

UNION

select * from
item_table
where find_in_set(40,itemids)>0
```